# Is there a PyQT equivalent to wx.FutureCall (calling a function after window is initialized and drawn)?

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt

I am trying to delay setting variables after my main window is opened. I have tried showEvent() but that doesn't work. I know in wxPython there is wx.FutureCall method to use in this type of situation:

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame): 

 def __init__(..frame init parms.., ..your init parms..): 
   wx.Frame.__init__(..frame init parms..) 
   self.Show() 
   wx.FutureCall(500,self.OnLoad)   #1/2 seconds from now to call OnLoad() 

 def OnLoad(self, ..your init parms..): 
   ..your init code.. 
   self.Refresh()
```

My question is: how can I delay doing some actions after my PyQT main window does its initialization and is finally shown? How can I do this:

```
class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self,parent=None):

    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)

    ... init stuff here...

    self.FutureCall(500,self.OnLoad)

  def OnLoad(self,event):
    ... my stuff here...
```

Thanks in advance!
-Paul

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know why `showEvent` is not working for you. For me it is working as expected. It is fired after the window is shown.

For the delayed call, you can use `QTimer.singleShot`:

```
class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):

    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

    ... init stuff here...

    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(500, self.OnLoad)

  def OnLoad(self):
    ... my stuff here...
```

Comment: Awesome. It works. Thanks! I was using it to open up a serial connection to my Arduino board - it needs some delay. *shrugs*