# how can i display data like a real time update? (pyqt)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

i got a problem that i have a method that continuously generate number and another method will call this method and display it on the `Qtextedit` when the button is clicked  but the GUI seems no response

there are my example code

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
 def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
  MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
  MainWindow.resize(176, 156)
  self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
  self.centralWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralWidget"))
  self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
  self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
  self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)

  self.text = QTextEdit()
  self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.text, 1, 0, 1, 1)

  self.pushButton.clicked.connect( self.Out)


  out = 0
  def number(self):
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        time.sleep(0.5)
        out = str(i)

  def Out(self):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    self.text.append(self.number())
    QtGui.qApp.processEvents()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

anyone can give me suggestion?

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding what you want to do. Do you want the number to count up in the background, and the display to update when you click the button? Do you want the display to update every time the number changes? Or something else?

Comment: The button should be connected to `self.number`, which can then pass the `out` value as an argument to `self.Out` on each turn of the loop. The argument value can then be appended to `self.text`. (PS: presumably, you are also going to need some mechanism for terminating the loop)

Answer (score 2):

Your `while True:` is a blocking call: once you enter this function, you don't go out. Therefore, your script hangs here.

One solution would be to execute that function in a separate thread (and it would therefore be non-blocking); another one would be to use a timer and a signal, as explained [in the answer to the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677462/is-there-a-pyqt-equivalent-to-wx-futurecall-calling-a-function-after-window-is).